# Two die simulator do-while-if-else-if error

Tags: java, random, dice

This is the assignment that was give to me. But I can't seem to understand what is wrong with my program and how to go about fixing it. It just keeps rolling dice non-stop and freezes my JCreator. I even tried changing the NUMBER value to 10 and it still does the same thing.

1. I have declared all the variables. You need to add code to simulate rolling the
   dice and keeping track of the doubles. Convert the algorithm below to Java and
   place it in the main method after the variable declarations, but before the output
   statements. You will be using several control structures: a while loop and an if-else-
   if statement nested inside another if statement. Use the indenting of the
   algorithm to help you decide what is included in the loop, what is included in the
   if statement, and what is included in the nested if-else-if statement.
2. To “roll” the dice, use the nextInt method of the random number generator to
   generate an integer from 1 to 6.

Comment: `If the value of the first die is the same as the value of the second die ... ncrement the number of times the dice were rolled ` What is this, and can it be made more readable?

Comment: I'm an experienced Java programmer, and I can't grab the logic of your code, simply because it's not indented properly. How could you? Do yourself a favor, and indent it. All decent IDEs (don't know if JCreator is one of them) do that with a single keyboard shortcut.

Comment: It's difficult to tell because of the indenting but you never actually increment count inside your do loop. You never test for anything in your loop. You just roll the die over and over.

Comment: Try moving your `while` conditional to the end of your body. Just above the `Sys.out.print()`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using a doop loop correctly. You have a do-loop and while loop, not a single do-loop. In the do-loop count never increases so the loop will never end. A do loop performs the first iteration before evaluating whether to continue.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class DiceSimulation
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int NUMBER = 10000;

        Random generator = new Random();

        int die1Value;
        int die2Value;
        int count = 0;
        int snakeEyes = 0;
        int twos = 0;
        int threes = 0;
        int fours = 0;
        int fives = 0;
        int sixes = 0;

        do{
            die1Value = generator.nextInt(6) + 1;
            System.out.println("You rolled: " + die1Value);

            die2Value = generator.nextInt(6) + 1;
            System.out.println("You rolled: " + die2Value);

            if (die1Value == die2Value)
            { 
                if(die1Value == 1)
                {
                    snakeEyes++;
                } 
                else if (die1Value == 2)
                {
                    twos++;
                } 
                else if (die1Value == 3)
                {
                    threes++;
                } 
                else if (die1Value == 4)
                {
                    fours++;
                } 
                else if (die1Value == 5)
                {
                    fives++;
                } 
                else if (die1Value == 6)
                {
                    sixes++;
                }
            }
            count++;
        }while (count < NUMBER);

        System.out.println ("You rolled snake eyes " + snakeEyes +
                " out of " + count + " rolls.");
        System.out.println ("You rolled double twos " + twos +
                " out of " + count + " rolls.");
        System.out.println ("You rolled double threes " + threes +
                " out of " + count + " rolls.");
        System.out.println ("You rolled double fours " + fours +
                " out of " + count + " rolls.");
        System.out.println ("You rolled double fives " + fives +
                " out of " + count + " rolls.");
        System.out.println ("You rolled double sixes " + sixes +
                " out of " + count + " rolls.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you  understood the do-while concept wrong.

The "do {...}" part (where you roll the dice) gets executed as long as the expression inside the while brackets is true.

Move the whole "if (die1Value == die2Value)" part (up to the "counter++;" line) into the do braces, and it should run.

Answer (score 1):

```
do
{
    die1Value = generator.nextInt(6) + 1;
    System.out.println("You rolled: " + die1Value);

    die2Value = generator.nextInt(6) + 1;
    System.out.println("You rolled: " + die2Value);
}
while (count <= NUMBER);
```

That first keyword **do** is taking the **while** to loop the whole block forever since the **count** variable is only incremented on the next block.
My advice is to remove the **do**:

```
//do
//{
    die1Value = generator.nextInt(6) + 1;
    System.out.println("You rolled: " + die1Value);

    die2Value = generator.nextInt(6) + 1;
    System.out.println("You rolled: " + die2Value);
//}
while (count <= NUMBER)
{
   ...
}
```

Since you already have a block after the while.

Comment: If count is <= NUMBER, that is an infinite loop doing nothing.